# How do we create instances of a class in JavaScript using new operator and factory pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to make a class (called `Foo`) like object in JavaScript that would let me create multiple instances of `Foo`. By multiple instances, I mean, each instance would maintain separate internal state. This is how I am achieving it.

```
var Foo = function() {
    function init(a) {
        this.a = a
    }

    function state() {
        return this.a
    }

    function getFoo() {
        return {
            init: init,
            state: state
        }
    }

    return {
        getFoo: getFoo
    }
}()

var a = Foo.getFoo()
var b = Foo.getFoo()
a.init(10)
b.init(20)
alert(a.state() + ', ' + b.state())
```

As you can see that the `Foo.getFoo()` seems to simulate the Factory pattern usually used in Java. The internal state is the variable `this.a`. I consider my attempt a success because `a.state()` and `b.state()` display two different internal states. However, this is purely my attempt without any knowledge of how these things are implemented in the industry.

Now, my questions may seem like a request for code review and is at the risk of getting closed, so I will try to make my questions as objective as possible.

1. How can the same code be implemented such that `new` operator can be used instead to create the new instances of a class with `this.a` as the internal state?
2. How is my code with the factory  pattern written in the industry?

Comment: [Check out this excellent resource](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Foo = function (a) {
    this.a = a;
};
Foo.prototype.state = function () {
    return this.a;
};

var a = new Foo(10);
a.state(); // 10
```

Bun you can also declare the **state** method from constructor itself like:

```
var Foo = function (a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.state = function () {
        return this.a;
    };
};
```

**UPDATE:** Factory pattern.

I usually use this for my factories:

```
var Foo = function (a) {
    this.a = a;
};
Foo.prototype.state = function () {
    return this.a;
};

var FooFactory = function () {};
FooFactory.prototype.create = function (a) {
    return new Foo(a);
};

var factory = new FooFactory();
var a = factory.create(20);
a instanceOf Foo; // true
a.state(); // 20
```

Comment: It doesn't help you, does it?

Comment: Don't say that :) This is exactly what I would do. The original code isn't really a producer of `Foo`. It just combines some functions to make it resemble `Foo`. Also having the object not be the factory simplifies the code.

Comment: @VladislavQulin It does help. I'll be accepting this answer in a couple of days once I wrap my mind around these concepts. :-)

Comment: var FooFactory = function () {};
FooFactory.create = function (a) {
    return new Foo(a);
};

var a = FooFactory.create(20);

Comment: @kayz1 with this way you won't be able to create derived classes. It's just a foreseing :)

Comment: @VladislavQulin One small question. Which approach would you prefer in your own code for a simple case like this? The `new` operator approach or the factory pattern approach?

Comment: @VladislavQulin In your `FooFactory` you use `Foo` but I don't see `Foo` defined anywhere in that code. Would you please help me understand your factory pattern code?

Comment: I work with large project with whole lot of different classes, so i prefer factory pattern. But it could be professional deformation. One for sure, you should come from your needs and don't make premature optimization.

Comment: @Lone Learner there's Foo in my code declared just above the factory :). Watch the first part of my answer.